# How to load a single bean for testing in Spring boot without loading the whole context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a class A that is dependent on bean B ( pretty simple bean, just a clock to be called ).
I want to unit test class A, how can this bean be loaded? @SpringBootTest loads the whole Context.

Comment: I would suggest looking to mocking with mockito, i don't think it is possibile to load only one bean without the container and even if it is possible it would still be slower than using mocks

Comment: If you want to unit test then unit test - that’s the whole point of IoC! Just mock/stub (either manually or with tooling) the other classes then create the class under test. Tools like SpringBoot Test are designed for more integration type tests.

Answer (score 9):

You should use the combination of two annotions:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@Import(
        value = {
                SomeSpringBean.class
        }
)
```

whereinto `@Import`'s value you can put your not mocking bean without spring-context building.
You can put through @Import any spring bean(class with @Configuration or @Component etc)
For mocking another bean in this test use @MockBean annotation.
The usage looks like that:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@Import(
        value = {
                SomeSpringBean.class
        }
)
class SomeSpringTest {

    @MockBean
    private MockedBean mock;

    @Autowired
    private SomeSpringBean bean;

...
}
```

see more in javadoc:

**Indicates one or more component classes to import — typically @Configuration classes.
Provides functionality equivalent to the  element in Spring XML. Allows for importing @Configuration classes, ImportSelector and ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar implementations, as well as regular component classes (as of 4.2; analogous to AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.register).
@Bean definitions declared in imported @Configuration classes should be accessed by using @Autowired injection. Either the bean itself can be autowired, or the configuration class instance declaring the bean can be autowired. The latter approach allows for explicit, IDE-friendly navigation between @Configuration class methods.**

Comment: What about "injecting" Beans that are interfaces (eg Repository)? In this case I got an error `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '...MyService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'MyRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}`

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. In this case, you should use `DataJpaTest` so as the database layer is taken care of. So it would look like


`@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
@Import(
        value = {
                MyService.class
        }
)
class SomeSpringTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private MyService service;
}`